# How do I conditionally render pages with a dropdown menu in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and I'm working on a website for a friend that uses a lot of react features. One thing this website needs is a navbar where every item in the navbar has a dropdown selection of additional nav items. I'm able to both render pages conditionally as independent nav items and create the hover dropdown on each nav item, but my issue comes into merging them together. I've tried a few things such as mapping through props twice, creating a large object where the nav item is a name and the dropdown items are subnames, but neither of those worked.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function Nav(props) {
    const [navItemList, setNavItemList] = useState([
        {name: 'About', dropdownItem1: 'About Me', dropdownItem2: 'About Tampa Bay', id: 1}, 
    ]);
    const { pages = [], setCurrentPage, currentPage } = props;
    return (
        <header className="flex-row">
            <h1 class="name-tag">
                <img src={"../../assets/Logo1.png"} />
            </h1>
            <nav>
                <NavItems items={navItemList} />
                <ul className="flex-row nav-list">
                {pages.map(navItem => (
                    <li className={`li-spacing text-format ${currentPage.name === navItem.name && 'navActive'}`} key={navItem.id}>
                       <span  onClick={() => { setCurrentPage(navItem) }}>{navItem.name}</span>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}
```

```
function App() {
  const [pages] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Home'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'About Me'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'About Tampa Bay'
    },
  ])
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(pages[0])
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav 
      pages={pages}
      currentPage={currentPage}
      setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
      ></Nav>
      <main>
        <Pages currentPage={currentPage}></Pages>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function NavItems(props) {
    const items = props.items
    return (
        <ul className=" flex-row nav-list">
            {/* map through the props so each navitem receives unique information */}
            {items.map((navItem) => (
                <div className="dropdown" key={navItem.id}>
                <li className="nav-list-item">{ navItem.name }</li>
                <div className="dropdown-item">
                    <p>{ navItem.dropdownItem1 }</p>
                    <p>{ navItem.dropdownItem2 }</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            )) }
        </ul>
    )
}

export default NavItems;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "merging them together"?

Comment: @AndréKrosby Can do. Right now I have two navbars setup: One has the functionality of being a dropdown but doesn't work when I click on any of the tags, the other navbar has 0 dropdown functionality but conditionally renders pages when each item is clicked. I'm trying to take these capabilities and make them into one navbar - that is, one that functions as a dropdown and allows me to click on items in the dropdown to render pages

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? This might need to be adjusted a bit to fit your styling needs.

```
const pages = {
  home: {
    name: 'Home',
    subPages: {},
  },
  about: {
    name: 'About',
    subPages: {
      aboutMe: {
        name: 'About Me',
      },
      aboutTampaBay: {
        name: 'About Tampa Bay',
      },
    },
  },
}

function App() {
  const [currentPageKey, setCurrentPageKey] = useState('home')

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav pages={pages} currentPage={currentPage} setCurrentPageKey={setCurrentPageKey} />
      <main>
        <Pages currentPage={pages[currentPageKey]} />
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

function Nav(props) {
  const { setCurrentPageKey, currentPage, pages } = props

  return (
    <header className="flex-row">
      <h1 class="name-tag">
        <img src={'../../assets/Logo1.png'} />
      </h1>
      <nav>
        <ul className="flex-row nav-list">
          {Object.entries(pages).map(([key, { name, subPages }]) => (
            <li className={`li-spacing text-format ${currentPage.name === name && 'navActive'}`} key={key}>
              <NavItems setCurrentPageKey={setCurrentPageKey} title={name} items={subPages} />
              <button onClick={() => setCurrentPageKey(key)}>{name}</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default function NavItems(props) {
  const { setCurrentPageKey, items, title } = props

  return (
    <ul className="flex-row nav-list">
      <div className="dropdown">
        <li className="nav-list-item">{title}</li>
        <div className="dropdown-item">
          {/* map through the props so each navitem receives unique information */}
          {Object.entries(items).map(([key, { name }]) => (
            <button onClick={() => setCurrentPageKey(key)} key={key}>
              {name}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: This definitely brought me a lot closer to my desired result. Still one piece missing, the page loading when clicke, but I think I can work with the code to get there. Thanks!